# console still running after sub-optimal termination

Tags: gurobi

I use gurobi to solve a LP problem. The method is barrier method and I disabled crossover, since I'm satisfied with the sub-optimal solution, and crossover takes forever.

However, after the sub-optimal termination, the console is still running (with huge use of memory). The solution takes 0.5 hours, but I have to wait for hours until I can continue.

I used python command line and Spyder.

Here is a summary of the (modified) log:

Barrier performed 500 interactions in 2000 seconds
Sub-optimal termination - objective XX

## (here it takes hours)

warning: a sub-optimal solution is available

## (here it takes hours)

The complete log is here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q2Z6QJNmXTWSRsJqxtEpUlCwhXnLIhFf

I expect the console would return the results immediately after the termination. The solving is fast, but it takes hours for something else.

Is there anything wrong? What can I do to make it faster?

Comment: Maybe your memory is exhausted and your OS is swapping to disk?  From the description you have given not much can be said, please post a complete log file (or deposit it somewhere for download).

Comment: I've added the log file in the main question. Thank you!

Comment: Do you monitor the memory usage of the process?  How much memory does your machine have?

Comment: During the solving process, the cpu is overloaded, the memory use is 7.2G/8G. After the solution, the cpu is released, the memory use even go up a bit to the full use (8G). Do you think it is a memory shortage issue that it requires more memory in the process of writing solutions etc.?

Comment: Yes, looks like you simply run out of memory and OS swapping induces huge hangs.

Comment: Too bad. I'm running another run, the memory use is ~6G out of 8G after the termination but before generating the warning message, so not at full use all the time. But still, if it's a memory problem, I can't do much. Thanks.